# Ado.net & Entity Framework : creating entities

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, ado.net

I'm creating an entity diagram and I have a question about the `StoreGeneratedPattern` property on the Id's. I have both `Identity` and `Computed` options, and I'm not sure when to use each one. I guess that I should use `Identity` when it is generated by the entity and use `Computed` when is a foreign key, since is generated by another identity. Am I right or is the other way around ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would just simply look at the **official** [MSDN documentation for this property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.metadata.edm.storegeneratedpattern(v=vs.110).aspx), you would see:

```
Member name    Description  
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Computed       A value is generated on both insert and update.
Identity       A value is generated on insert and remains unchanged on update.
None           A value indicating that it is not a server generated property.
```

So if you have a PK column that's an `INT IDENTITY`, then it's clear - use the `Identity` value.

The `Computed` value should be used for **computed columns** in your database tables, that are typically calculated on insert and re-calculated on update. This is **NOT** intended for foreign key columns! Those are just *regular* columns - do **NOT** set any `StoreGeneratedPattern` value for those!!